# Template argument type deduction won't work within a function object

Tags: c++, templates, std-function, type-deduction

I have a template function taking another function with templated argument type.

When using it I have to specify the argument type explicitly (1) otherwise it won't compile (2).

```
template<typename T>
void process(const std::function<void(const T &)>& f)
{
   // ...
}

process<Foo>( [&](const Foo& arg){/*...*/} ); // (1) Ok!

// process( [&](const Foo& arg){/*...*/} ); // (2) Won't Work!
```

Is there any trick to let (2) work?

Comment: Why are you taking in an `std::function` instead of a generic functor?

Comment: C++ version, please?

Comment: @Boiethios in the absence of an older tag, [c++] denotes up-to-date C++, so C++14 right now.

Comment: It doesn't work because the closure type of the lambda must be *converted* to a `std::function`, it doesn't match the function parameter type for deduction to take place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just let the compiler figure out the exact type of the whole function :

```
template<typename T>
void process(T&& f)
{
   // ...
}
```

Now both your function calls will work.

Comment: how can I constraint the function having specific signature?

void(const TYPE &)